# vewport units in iframe

Tags: css, iframe, viewport

I have a web app that must be used in PCs with different screen sizes. I use viewport concept and all sizes using vh/vw units to have the same layout in all screens.

Unfortunately, I must use an iframe to show some pages. In these pages the vw/vh units refers to iframe size istead of screensize. This will change completely the layout.

There is a way to override this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the layout to look like in an iframe? Do you want it to 'think' it has a much bigger viewport and then scale down, or is it to think it has a much bigger viewport and the user has to scroll to see bits of it?

Comment: Hi, my goal is to have same elements in and out the iframe to appear in tha same way i.e. a  text with the size of 0.2vw, being the iframe 60% of the screen , noiw appears 60% smaller than the text in main window. I know that I can do it defining different css for pages in irame, but in this way it's strictly conected to iframe size. If it will change, all css sizes must change, I looks for a more general solution, if exist

Comment: OK, so you want the iframe to 'think' it has the viewport size of the 'host' site and if the user has to scroll, they have to scroll?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what i search

Comment: Just set your font size in pixels rather than vw units.

Comment: Is it more than text size that is the concern - ie the whole layout depends on vw etc  units and you want to preserve that?

Comment: Hi Brett, this do not helps. In this case it will not work properly in different screen sizes, as my case

Comment: Do you have complete control of the iframe HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: Hi A.Haworth, yes, correct

Comment: Pass the vw and vh size as parameters to the iframe and within the iframe use CSS variables instead of actual vw/vh/vmin units. (Requires a little bit of Javascript).